# Linear transformation of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

We have vectors:

$$a=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
2\\
0
\end{bmatrix}b=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
c=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

The linear transformation $A:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ is :

$$A a=a+b$$
$$Ab=2a$$
$$Ac=c$$

We need to find the matrix for basis $B=\{a,b,c\}$ and the standard basis of $R^3$

I tried:

I would put the vectors of linear transformation in rows
$$A \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 &0\\
2 & 4 &0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
And then I would do matrix multiplication:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 3 &0\\
2 & 4 &0\\
0& 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
3\\
0
\end{bmatrix}=...$$

I would get the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of $A$ that is matrix with respect to $B$ is$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$This is independent of the definitions of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Now, if$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\2&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix},$$(the columns of $P$ are the vectors of $B$) then the matrix of $A$ with respect to the standard basis is$$P.A.P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 5 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$